# How to warn before editing or saving a buffer whose underlying file no longer exists?

Tags: buffers, text-editing, warning, saving

(**NB:** In this post, I will use expressions like "a buffer's *underlying* file" to mean, in the Emacs' documentation's terminology, "the file a buffer is *visiting*", i.e. the value of `(buffer-file-name SOME-BUFFER)` for the buffer `SOME-BUFFER`.)

---

Sometimes it happens that a buffer's underlying file gets modified on disk by some other process.

If one tries to modify such a buffer, Emacs warns of the on-disk change, and requests confirmation; e.g. (in the minibuffer):

```
one_really_busy_file changed on disk; really edit the buffer? (y, n, r or C-h)
```

Furthermore, if after responding `y` to such a confirmation request, one modifies such a buffer, and then attempts to *save* the modified buffer, then Emacs once again issues a warning and a confirmation request; e.g.:

```
one_really_busy_file has changed since visited or saved.  Save anyway? (y or n)
```

To be sure, Emacs does not regard *all* modifications to a buffer's underlying file as being equally worthy of all this fuss.  Changes to the underlying file's permissions, for example, do not elicit any of this.

Strangely enough, according to out-of-the-box Emacs, a buffer's underlying file's ***disappearance*** *also* fails to warrant such a response!

To be more specific, Emacs remains perfectly quiet if one modifies a buffer whose underlying file has ***disappeared***, and—even more surprising—, it remains equally silent when one then *saves* (`C-x C-s`) the modified buffer (thereby *re-creating* the underlying file).

---

**Q:** How can I get Emacs to issue a warning and a confirmation request also ***when one attempts to modify a buffer*** whose underlying file has disappeared?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```lisp
(add-hook 'before-save-hook 'foo)

(defun foo ()
  (when (and (buffer-file-name)  (not (file-exists-p (buffer-file-name))))
    (unless (y-or-n-p "No such file.  Create it?")
      (error "OK, not saved"))))
```

However, this could be regarded as a feature: Emacs creates a file for a buffer you ask it to save.

But if you don't like this behavior you might consider filing a bug report (enhancement request): `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: Thank you!  To be clear, the condition described in my post is the one corresponding to `(and (buffer-file-name) (not (file-exists-p (buffer-file-name))))`, whereas the one in your function is `(not (and (buffer-file-name) (file-exists-p (buffer-file-name))))`; they are not equivalent.  Also, I would like a similar warning+confirmation right before I attempt to *modify* a buffer whose underlying file does not exist.  To extend your idea to do this would require a hook that would get triggered when one attempts to modify a buffer.  Is there such a hook?

Comment: Oops. I corrected the condition.

Comment: Please don't add questions to your question (including in comments). One question per post, please.

Comment: My "added" question was *already* in my original post: I wrote (emphasis added) "How can I get Emacs to issue a warning and a confirmation request also when one attempts to *modify* a buffer whose underlying file has disappeared?"

Comment: Yes, and it shouldn't have been. Someone wanting to know how to do one doesn't necessarily want to know how to do the other. And answers for one aren't necessarily answers for the other. Q & A are for everyone, including people searching/googling. And in particular, multiple questions invite evolving questions...

Comment: I asked ONE question in my original post.  You answered a DIFFERENT one from the one I asked, and now are blaming me for it.

Comment: @Drew, I think you mean `write-file-functions`. `before-save-hook` functions are not checked for success/failure.

Comment: @rpluim: I visit a file, then delete the file (e.g. using Dired). Then I try `C-x C-s` in the buffer. The code I show here takes effect. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Drew `before-save-hook` is wrapped with `with-demoted-errors`, so calling `error` inside it will have no effect. `write-file-functions` are wrapped with `run-hook-with-args-until-success`, so you can just return `t` when you want to prevent the save.

Comment: @rpluim: (1) I don't understand the use of `with-demoted-errors` without a `FORMAT` first arg, in `basic-save-buffer`. Is it correct? (2) In what case does the code I presented not work (example)? Thx.

Comment: @Drew, the docstring in my Emacs says it's allowed to be a function "For backward compatibility". If you answer 'n' to the `y-or-n-p` prompt using your example, the file is still saved.

Comment: @rpluim: You're right on both counts. Please post an answer that uses `write-file-hooks`, and I'll delete mine. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `write-file-functions` hook to do this. It's what's called an "abnormal" hook, which means its return value is taken into account, unlike `before-save-hook`. In this case, if it returns `t`, the `save-buffer' command returns without saving the buffer. E.g.

```
(add-hook 'write-file-functions #'foo)

(defun foo ()
  (when (and (buffer-file-name) (not (file-exists-p (buffer-file-name))))
    (not (y-or-n-p "No such file.  Create it?"))))
```